# Spring boot application is not able to inject CDI beans.

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, cdi

I am trying to use CDI created beans in my springboot application. The spring boot project is having all the access to the required CDI based DI classes but @Inject is not able to inject the CDI beans into the spring boot project.

Note: I have tried to add below line in my spring context file as well to solve this issue:

```
<bean class="org.cdisource.springintegration.CdiBeanFactoryPostProcessor" />
```

But I was getting error as:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cdisource.springintegration.CdiBeanFactoryPostProcessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:607) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:846) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:825) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:325) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:274) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:437) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1428) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:666) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:633) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:390) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1276) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 more
```

And the required dependency for the "org.cdisource.springintegration.CdiBeanFactoryPostProcessor" is not found in the maven repository.

If any body is having any solution regarding this CDI and spring integration please do share the concept.

Comment: Looks like a simple case of adding the dependency for the class to the pom, perhaps.                      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.cdisource.springbridge</groupId>
      <artifactId>springbridge</artifactId>
    </dependency>

Comment: I tried adding this same dependency but this is dependency is not available in the maven repository, so could not be downloaded in the project. I have tried searching it with "artifactId: springbridge"  when the POM.xml was complaining that the dependency could not be downloaded. But there is nothing with this artifact in the maven repo.  It says : "Missing artifact org.cdisource.springbridge:springbridge"

Comment: Is there any reason you want to stick with CDI ? Why not just convert the app to Spring (put an @Component on each CDI bean essentially) ?

Comment: I wish but I cant do that, major portion of the project is CDI and i am trying to ingrate one small module of spring boot into it, and have to reuse the other modules for the business logic.

Comment: Have you found a solution?